# How to import module from non-relative paths in Visual studio 2015

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6, compiler-options

I am working on angular 4 project using gulp in Visual studio 2015.
I got the `Visual Studio 2015 QuickStart` from [here](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015).

- tsc version: 2.5.2

My project structure:

```
src
└──angular
     └──common
           └──models
                └──items.ts
     └──ui
         └──components
                └──items.component.ts
```

**items.ts**

```
export module items {
  export const listOfItems = [1,2,3];
}
```

I want to use non-relative path when importing everything within my src folder, i.e.:

**items.component.ts**

```
import { items } from 'items';
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file (which is on the same level as `src`):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried adding this into the `compilerOptions`:

```
"baseUrl": "." //it doesn't help.
```

after that:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/angular/*" // still nothing.
      ]
}
```

I also added `rootDirs` but I am still getting this error:

```
Can't find module 'items'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, be sure that you have installed *[TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 - v2.5.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True)*, after that:

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
     "paths": {
     "@models/*": [ "angular/common/models/*" ]
     }
    //..
  }
}
```

**usage:**

```
import { items } from '@models/items';
```

So, what's happening here:

`*` is pointing to the actual name of our file, so in our case after `@models` there is `*` which is pointing to `items`, and `items` is somewhere inside `angular/common/models/*`.

Also, we should add this into `systemjs.config.js` so that the path can be resolved:

```
 System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/',
      "@models/*": ["rootDist/angular/common/models/*"]
                        ^
                        where you keep your files, for example dist/
    }
    // other things..
  });
```

And another important thing here is to **restart the visual studio**

*I've also tried unload/reload the project, but that doesn't help.*